# XA transactions in Ballerina with mysql

Tags: ballerina

Tried to follow [1] using mysql instead of h2. However there seem to be issues when this is added between transaction block. Have included mysql lib under bre/lib folder. Following is the endpoint definition and transaction block. When running the .bal file after table creation a tranaction is initiated but then it directly goes to retry transaction and finally aborts it. Any idea what is missing here? [1] https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/xa-transactions.html

```
endpoint mysql:Client testDB1 {
    host: "localhost",
    port: 3306,
    name: "customerdb",
    username: "root",
    password: "root",
    poolOptions: { maximumPoolSize: 5, isXA:true },
    dbOptions: { useSSL: false }
};

endpoint mysql:Client testDB2 {
    host: "localhost",
    port: 3306,
    name: "salarydb",
    username: "root",
    password: "root",
    poolOptions: { maximumPoolSize: 5, isXA:true },
    dbOptions: { useSSL: false }
};


  transaction with retries = 3, oncommit = onCommitFunction, onabort = onAbortFunction {
      var retWithKey = testDB1->updateWithGeneratedKeys("INSERT INTO
                                CUSTOMER(NAME) VALUES ('Anne')", ());
        string generatedKey;
        match retWithKey {
            (int, string[]) y => {
                var (count, ids) = y;
                generatedKey = ids[0];
                io:println("Inserted row count: " + count);
                io:println("Generated key: " + generatedKey);
            }
            error err => io:println("Insert to customer table failed: "
                                    + err.message);
        }

        ret = <int>generatedKey;
        int key = -1;
        match ret {
            int retInt => key = retInt;
            error err => io:println("Converting key to string failed: "
                                    + err.message);
        }
        io:println("Generated key for the inserted row: " + key);

        ret = testDB2->update("INSERT INTO SALARY (ID, VALUE)
                               VALUES (?, ?)", key, 2500);
        handleUpdate(ret, "Insert to SALARY table");


   } onretry {
       io:println("Retrying transaction");
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

This occurs when you are trying to perform an XA transaction with two databases in the same server. This is a known issue reported at [1]. As explained in [1] the root cause behind this issue was found but the suggested solution did not work on mysql due to a bug[2] in mysql side. We will be further investigating this issue.

[1] https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues/7963

[2] https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=78498